# Is it possible to use Zip more than 2 Observables using RxJava 2.x?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava 2.x, and have 3 observables (if important, specifically publish subjects).

I like to run them all once, and get results once. I was using `Observable.zip()` operator for this kind of processes. However It looks like Zip operator doesn't support more than 2 observables.

Is there other operator to combine more than 3 observables just like zip?

```
Observable.zip(
        getData(),
        getOtherData(),
        getTemplate(),
        (o1,o2,o3)->{

        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually,

It [supports](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html), I didn't return value, and IDE's error message was misleading.

```
Observable.zip(
        getData(),
        getOtherData(),
        getTemplate(),
        (o1,o2,o3)->{
            return null;
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a [zip function variant](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.functions.Function3-) that zips 3 sources.